# How to render foreign characters on webpage

Tags: html, unicode, mura

**Problem:** I am not able to display characters correctly in Japanese, Chinese, Russian and so forth on the webpage. I am able to get some characters to display correctly in the Spanish version. However, for other languages, it breaks. I am not sure how to approach this. I am also using Mura CMS for the website and was not able to find a way to render the characters through their.

I am seeing the following on the webpage.

```
<p><strong>Spanish</strong><br />
    ATENCI&Oacute;N: si habla espa&ntilde;ol, tiene a su disposici&oacute;n servicios gratuitos de asistencia ling&uuml;&iacute;stica. Llame al 1-321-268-6111. (TTY: 1-800-955-8771)</p>

<p><strong>French Creole</strong><br />
    ATANSYON: Si w pale Krey&ograve;l Ayisyen, gen s&egrave;vis &egrave;d pou lang ki disponib gratis pou ou. Rele 1-321-268-6111. (TTY: 1-800-955-8771)</p>

<p><strong>Vietnamese</strong><br />
    CH&Uacute; &Yacute;: N?u b?n n&oacute;i Ti?ng Vi?t, c&oacute; c&aacute;c d?ch v? h? tr? ng&ocirc;n ng? mi?n ph&iacute; d&agrave;nh cho b?n. G?i s? 1-321-268-6111. (TTY: 1-800-955-8771)</p>

<p><strong>Portuguese</strong><br />
    ATEN&Ccedil;&Atilde;O: Se fala portugu&ecirc;s, encontram-se dispon&iacute;veis servi&ccedil;os lingu&iacute;sticos, gr&aacute;tis. Ligue para 1-321-268-6111. (TTY: 1-800-955-8771)</p>

<p><strong>Chinese</strong><br />
    ??????????????????????????????1-321-268-6111. (TTY: 1-800-955-8771)</p>

<p><strong>French</strong><br />
    ATTENTION: Si vous parlez fran&ccedil;ais, des services d'aide linguistique vous sont propos&eacute;s gratuitement. Appelez le 1-321-268-6111. (TTY: 1-800-955-8771)</p>

<p><strong>Tagalog</strong><br />
    PAUNAWA: Kung nagsasalita ka ng Tagalog, maaari kang gumamit ng mga serbisyo ng tulong sa wika nang walang bayad. Tumawag sa 1-321-268-6111. (TTY: 1-800-955-8771)</p>

<p><strong>Russian</strong><br />
    ????????: ???? ?? ???????? ?? ??????? ?????, ?? ??? ???????? ?????????? ?????? ????????. ??????? 1-321-268-6111. (TTY: 1-800-955-8771)</p>

<p><br />
    <strong>Arabic</strong></p>

<p style="text-align: right;">??????: ??? ??? ????? ???? ?????? ??? ????? ???????? ??????? ?????? ?? ???????. ???? ???? 1-123-862-1116 (??? ???? ???? ?????. (TTY: 1-800-955-8771)</p>

<p><strong>Italian </strong><br />
    ATTENZIONE: In caso la lingua parlata sia l'italiano, sono disponibili servizi di assistenza linguistica gratuiti. Chiamare il numero 1-321-268-6111. (TTY: 1-800-955-8771)</p>

<p><strong>German</strong><br />
    ACHTUNG: Wenn Sie Deutsch sprechen, stehen Ihnen kostenlos sprachliche Hilfsdienstleistungen zur Verf&uuml;gung. Rufnummer: 1-321-268-6111. (TTY: 1-800-955-8771)</p>

<p><strong>Korean</strong><br />
    ??: ???? ????? ??, ?? ?? ???? ??? ???? ? ????. 1-321-268-6111. ??? ??? ????. (TTY: 1-800-955-8771)</p>
```

[image]

Comment: What is a foreign character? English is foreign to the Japanese

Comment: @EdHeal: I mean is I am not able to generate characters like Japanese, Russian, Arabic, Farsi and so on

Comment: Use utf encoding

Comment: @EdHeal I changed utf-8 to utf-8-bom and the text did not generate correctly

Comment: What is in the http headers to do with encoding?

Comment: @EdHeal: Sorry, I am confused then. Can you please elaborate by utf encoding? I am new to this

Comment: In the http headers it tells the browser the content of the payload

Comment: @EdHeal: okay. I figured out a different approach. Thank you for your time